# Can I use an old Xbox 360 AV cord on Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one

Every year I go to my grandmother's house for Christmas and Summer break. My parents are pretty sure that they will give me an Xbox One for Christmas this year. My grandma only has 2 TVs in her house though. One CRT, and another flatscreen. I am not allowed to put consoles on the flatscreen because people use it for watching TV. So I have heard that you should use an HDMI to AV converter, but I wanted to know if I could just use my old Xbox 360 AV cord on the One.

Answer (score 4):

No, the Xbox One does not support the AV cables used with the Xbox 360. The only output featured is for HDMI.

For connecting an Xbox One to a TV that only has the older AV ports, rather then HDMI input, your best bet is to use a HDMI cable with a HDMI to AVI converter. You can generally find these at an electrical wholesaler, although electric retailers will likely have a similar solution, too.